# How do I set up a nested URL pattern for /category/subcategory/post in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-urls

I've looked through several answers and I cannot seem to figure out how to do this. My best guess is this has something to do with all of these answers are specific to writing function based views.

The problem:

I have a portal where I want the URL structure to be:

/portal/engagement/engagement_name/finding/finding_name

So I've tried several things and this is the closest I can get:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', login_required(CustomerDashboard.as_view()), name='portal_dashboard'),
    path('engagement/add', login_required(EngagementCreateView.as_view()), name='engagement_create'),
    path('engagement/<slug:slug>/', login_required(EngagementDetailView.as_view()), name='engagement_detail'),
    path('engagement/<slug:slug>/edit', login_required(EngagementUpdateView.as_view()), name='engagement_update'),
    path('engagement/<slug:slug>/finding/add', login_required(FindingCreateView.as_view()), name='finding_create'),
    path('finding/<slug:slug>', login_required(FindingDetailView.as_view()), name='finding_detail'),
    path('finding/<slug:slug>/edit', login_required(FindingUpdateView.as_view()), name='finding_update'),
]
```

If I try to do something like `engagement/<slug:slug>/finding/<slug:slug>/ it just errors. I've tried to follow some answers like choosing the slug field (i.e.` slug:engagement_slug``` but none of it works.

I'm using class based views. My models are:

Company
Engagement (FK to Company)
Finding (FK to Engagement)

I'm not sure what other code I can provide to help. I've read some other options on overriding the  get_object method and passing the slug as a **kwarg. I'm just not sure what is the "right" way to do this.

EDIT: I should also add the slug field for each model is "AutoSlugField" `from django_extensions.db.fields import AutoSlugField`.

Comment: You need to give the parameters a different name, so `engagement/<slug:slug>/finding/<slug:slug2>/`

Comment: In my models, you mean? Instead of naming the slug field slug in all the models, have them like "finding_slug = models.whatever..."